# Blank window when i press select media link

Tags: media

I have created a video content type, created a video field, and used media asset.
When I create a video node and click on "Select media," a blank popup shows up. In this blank popup, I have to choose in which way to upload file.

In the Firefox error console I see the following error:

> TypeError: this.contentWindow.Drupal.media is undefined

I am using Drupal 7.20 and the latest version of the Media module.

Comment: Had that before. And it turned out to be a conflict with some js in a custom module.

Comment: I have admin_menu, ckeditor, pathauto, transliteration, views, admin_language. Don't u recall what it was exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry Heiachi, the conflict originated from a custom module.

Comment: I 've just tested with admin_menu, ckeditor, pathauto, and views enabled. No problems there. Try disabling transliteration and admin_language.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug or Chrome Developer tools and look at the "Network traffic" and "Console" windows. I'll bet your getting a 404 or a JS related error in 1 of those windows.

You can then correct your server file permissions, fix the JS code error, or whatever.

You dont just have a blank page -- you have a blank page and an error reported somewhere.